# Querying election results

Tags: arcgis, arcmap

I'm building electoral maps from mayoral races in ArcGIS over the last 3 election cycles, trying to see if a particular part of town votes like the rest of the town.

There are multiple candidates for mayor and an example table looks like this:

```
PRECINCT_NUMBER    TOTAL_BALLOTSCAST    CANDIDATE1   CANDIDATE2  CANDIDATE3
           500                  1000           500          300         200
           501                  2000           800          700         500
           502                  1000           400          500         100
```

I can show how a *specific candidate* did by precinct by calcuating `candidatex / total_ballotcast` to give percentages for each precinct, and display the precincts by category of percentage by candidate.

However, I am also trying to show who was the biggest winner in each precinct by percentage and I am not sure how to query the data to reflect this.

Comment: But without telling us what the core data looks like? It's a sort of psychic exercise, is it?

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish this within ArcMap:

Create a new field (e.g. `WINNER`). Use [field calculator](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005s0000002m000000) to compare the values from three fields and output the maximum (biggest winner) as follows:

Check "Show Codeblock" to do an advanced python expression in the field calculator tool.

The *expression* should be:

```
find_winner(!CANDIDATE1!, !CANDIDATE2!, !CANDIDATE3!)
```

The *pre-logic script code* is where you define the function `find_winner` that the expression is calling:

```
def find_winner(a, b, c):
    if a > b and a > c:      # if a got more votes than b and c
        return "Candidate 1"
    elif b > a and b > c:    # if b got more votes than a and c
        return "Candidate 2"
    elif c > a and c > b:    # if c got more votes than a and b
        return "Candidate 3"
    else:
        return "TIE?"
```

Once `WINNER` is populated with values, it should be straightforward to symbolize your polygons based on that attribute.